# Get a result only when all the conditions are met in my sql where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really struggling with this situation.

I have a table made of symptoms and diseases, for each disease I have n symptoms, now, I want that the SQL retrieve the disease id only if all the Symptoms Ids on the where clause met with all the symptoms for one disease.

Let me explain it with an example. And show you what I tried to do.

```
|         13 |             3 |
|         16 |             3 |
|         17 |             3 |
|         18 |             3 |
|         19 |             3 |
|         20 |             3 |
|         21 |             3 |
|         22 |             3 |
|         23 |             3 |
|         24 |             3 |
|         25 |             3 |
|         26 |             3 |
|          5 |             4 |
|          9 |             4 |
|         28 |             4 |
|          5 |             5 |
|         23 |             5 |
```

The chart above is a part of this symptoms-disease table (compose), the left column is the symptoms and the right one the diseases.
Let's say I want the disease with the id n° 4, this disease is linked only with 3 symptoms (5, 9, 28), so I imagined that a SQL like

```
SELECT disease_id
FROM compose
WHERE symptom_id = 5
AND
symptom_id = 9
AND
symptom_id = 28;
```

but this SQL returns an Empty Set, I don't really understand why, It does not sound hard, but I honestly not seeing what's wrong. Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Answer is already given, I only want to say why the query you tried gave empty set, it is because of "AND" clause you used. As "WHERE" clause is evaluated for each row, in your example "no rows" will satisfy all the three Symptom id together.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you need to aggregate by disease and then express your assertion on the number of diseases:

```
SELECT disease_id
FROM compose
WHERE symptom_id IN (5, 9, 28)
GROUP BY disease_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT symptom_id) = 3;
```

If you want to exclusively match 3 and *only* three symptoms, then we need to rephrase the query a bit:

```
SELECT disease_id
FROM compose
GROUP BY disease_id
HAVING
    SUM(symptom_id = 5) > 0  AND
    SUM(symptom_id = 9) > 0  AND
    SUM(symptom_id = 28) > 0 AND
    SUM(symptom_id NOT IN (5, 9, 28)) = 0;
```

Comment: Although it would be odd for a disease to have the same symptoms twice

Comment: Thanks, I really dont knew the existence of the HAVING clause, but, my original problem stills. If I use the same SQL than you wrote and add a new symptom id, like symptom id = 30. The SQL still returns the disease id 4, even when that symptom is not linked with that disease.
What I was trying to say, maybe I won't clear is I only want that the SQL retrieve a disease ***ONLY*** if all the symptoms match. So if I use the symptoms 5,9,28,***30*** for example, this should retrieve nothing.